# Alternative for remove method for IE

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

My current code is :

```
onremoveItem :(e)->
  e.currentTarget.remove()
```

Its not working in IE but works fine in Chrome and Firefox. I know remove() is not supported in IE. Whats the best solution that can be applied so that i works on IE, chrome and Firefox?

Comment: Create as a jquery object and remove the element `$(e.currentTarget).remove()`

Answer (score 2):

Since you've tagged this with jQuery, **use jQuery**:

```
$(e.currentTarget).remove()
```

The entire point of jQuery is that it normalizes weird incompatible behaviors of browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Create as a jquery object and remove the element

```
 $(e.currentTarget).remove()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try jQuery:

```
$(e.currentTarget).remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with javascript:

```
e.currentTarget.parentNode.removeChild(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

"e.currentTarget" is "undefined" in my IE. It works for me with the following code and is tested in FF, Chrome, IE and Edge.

```
var e = $(".class"); //selector to select element directly.
e.parentNode.removeChild(this);
```